# Missing Google Cloud Storage menu item in console

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console

Project Name is **Google Storage Project**
Project ID is **anjanesh**
But in the console, I can no longer see Google Cloud Storage. Shows only AppEngine, Datastore and BigQuery. Where did my Google Cloud Storage menu item go ? I had a number of buckets in it.

Comment: Also, if I goto https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect#project:636020870316:storage and click on online browser, it goes to https://cloud.google.com/console/project/636020870316/storage/undefined

Comment: This has been magically resolved. Thanks.